# How to post a URL containting curly braces and colons

Tags: ruby

I need to do a POST request for a URL containing curly braces and colons:

```
http://192.168.178.23/emoncms/input/post.json?json={power:200}&apikey=671b341330a7b1a4c20bf8ae7dd1faf1&time=12345677890
```

I tried this:

```
uri = URI("http://192.168.178.23/emoncms/input/post.json")

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, "json" => "{power:200}", "apikey" => "671b341330a7b1a4c20bf8ae7dd1faf1", "time" => "1234567890")
```

But this results in:

```
json=%7BPVCurrent%3A3.0%7D&apikey=671b341330a7b1a4c20bf8ae7dd1faf1&time=1406144643
```

The service I am calling can't parse this string. How can I force ruby not to encode these values?

Comment: If you're doing a post request, should the JSON be in the body instead of a query parameter?

Comment: Url cannot contain neither curly braces or colons. It is not only ruby thing, this is how url works. Also, as mentioned above, you do not send params with url when using POST verb, you just send them a s part of request body. It seems to me that you want to send json request, not http request.

Comment: For shure it's the best way to POST the valuas as part of the body - but the API I'm talking with didn't do this so I have to place the json in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

The URL query values have to be encoded, but you're not going about this the right way. Use a class designed to manipulate URIs:

```
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://192.168.178.23/emoncms/input/post.json')
url.query = URI::encode_www_form(
  {
    'json' => '{power:200}',
    'apikey' => '671b341330a7b1a4c20bf8ae7dd1faf1',
    'time' => 12345677890
  }
)

url.to_s # => "http://192.168.178.23/emoncms/input/post.json?json=%7Bpower%3A200%7D&apikey=671b341330a7b1a4c20bf8ae7dd1faf1&time=12345677890"
```

Both Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), and [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) are designed to work with URIs. Of the two, Addressable::URI is the more feature-complete.

[`URI::encode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) basically treats the hash as if its contents were the values from a form, and encodes them as a URL query. `url.query =` then appends that to `url`.